# check `$(AndroidAapt2CompileExtraArgs)` and `$(AndroidAapt2LinkExtraArgs)` to see if they include any `aapt` command line argume

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Unknown option `-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar`. Please check `$(AndroidAapt2CompileExtraArgs)` and `$(AndroidAapt2LinkExtraArgs)` to see if they include any `aapt` command line arguments that are no longer valid for `aapt2` and ensure that all other arguments are valid for `aapt2`.  Login.Android

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [document](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/master/Documentation/guides/messages/apt0001.md) that described this problem:

**Issue**:

> The new Android aapt2 resource tool has different commandline
> arguments to the older aapt tool. These are generally incompatible
> with each other.

**Solution**:

If you are receiving this error, check that the values provided in

```
<AndroidAapt2LinkExtraArgs/>
<AndroidAapt2CompileExtraArgs>
```

are valid for aapt2. You can use aapt2 compile and aapt2 link to view the list of valid arguments.